# Size of directory with millions of sub directories without `du'

Tags: shell, directory, disk-usage, size

I have a folder with millions of sub directories and in each sub directory a file.

I need to get the size of the complete directory size. I've used `du` but it took **17 hours** (on a M.2 SSD) to complete the command, and in that time-frame the size will have changed rendering the output outdated/useless.

An example tree structure of the data would look like this:

```
  parent/
  ├── sub1/
  │   ├── sub1.1/
  │   │   └── file.txt
  │   ├── sub1.2/
  │   │   │── sub1.2.1/
  │   │   │   └── file.txt
  │   │   └── file.txt
  │   └── file.txt
  ├── sub2/
  │   ├── sub2.1/
  │   │   └── file.txt

...etc...
```

The amount and the depth of sub directories is unknown.

### What I've tried

As stated before I've tried

- `du -csh parent/`
- `tree parent/`

I've searched google and cannot find any solution that would work. The only real solution I can come up with is putting the parent folder on an empty harddisk then use `df -h`.

If you can find a better solution / script / program, feel free to share it!

Comment: If other directories in the filesystem aren't that problematic, you could do find the size of those and subtract from disk usage reported by `df`.

Comment: dedicated filesystem/subvolume for this tree or quotas or manual track changes with inotify... or change the software that creates this tree to help keep track of things

Comment: @frostschutz *manual track changes with inotify*  With millions of subdirectories, likely being created continually?  [I wouldn't even bother with inotify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806488/inotify-missing-events).  The answer is either "change the software" or "give it a dedicated filesystem" if knowing how much data it creates is important.